# What is the difference between many core and multi core?

Tags: embedded

These terms seem to be same but in a guest lecture i found that they are not but i have not been able to find the difference even after googling around for a while .

Comment: What about the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-core_processor): "The terms many-core and massively multi-core are sometimes used to describe multi-core architectures with an especially high number of cores (tens or hundreds)." For me that looks pretty straightforward (I had no clue what many-core's are either).

Comment: Hmm.  I saw "multicore" and thought of wiring!  What does that say about me?

Answer (score 5):

Multicore typically refers to devices with 2-8 or so cores in them.

Manycore typically refers to devices with dozens or hundreds of cores.

As far as I know, there's no hard definition of when you go from a multicore to manycore device.  My guess would be that the words were defined by someone's marketing department...

One difference between them is that manycore systems will only run efficiently with software that is designed with multiple cores in mind - single threaded software will be extra slow on such equipment.

Comment: It seems to me that manycore tend to be more specialized and do a smaller subset of operations well than the cores in a multicore processor.  This would likely be due to the sheer number of cores with respect to the silicon area.  Anyone else have similar or different experiences?

Answer (score 2):

Multi-core: A system with 2-8 cores and particularly does not implement parallel architecture (either at HW or SW)

Many-core: A system with hundreds or thousands of cores and implements parallel architecture (HW and SW).

A cluster may be made of Multi-core and Many-core systems.

Comment: Do you have any references for that or is it just your opinion?

Comment: Do not remember exactly. I read somewhere during my coursework especially when you have to deal with parallelism (HW and SW). I will post if I find a reference.

Comment: May be this [link](http://goparallel.sourceforge.net/ask-james-reinders-multicore-vs-manycore/) supports my arguments. In my point of view, if you have **multi-core** system, then you can't optimize HW for parallelism (or with little extent), you have to work more on SW. But in case of **many-cores** systems, it is possible to have better possibility of parallelism on HW and SW.

Comment: That's probably a good link to include as a reference along with a bit of a description of what it's about. Note that I wasn't doubting your answer, it's just always good to have a reference for anything that may be a bit more of an industry accepted term than a hard definition.

Answer (score 0):

Multicore: Main the execution speed of a sequential program.

Many-core: Maintain Execution throughput of a parallel application